# How to convert RGB input to grayscale for YOLO v3 Training?

Tags: rgb, grayscale, yolo

I am using the YOLO V3 and my dataset is RGB images however I want to train the network on grayscale version of same dataset. So My question is Is there any method in YOLO v3 that can convert my RGB dataset to grayscale for training automatically or I must first convert my dataset from RGB to grayscale and then feed to the network? OR is it possible to do any pre-processing or conversion using OpenCV or any other library?

Answer (score 0):

I think setting `channels=1` in cfg file, will work if you already have grayscale datasets.

According to this issue : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/3201 ,you have to train your model using grayscale dataset if you want to make inference (detection) on grayscale images. So, pre-processing using opencv is probably the easiest : `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Answer (score 0):

You must first write a program with the following content:(
It can help you complete the conversion from RBG and BGR color space to grayscale space)

```
import cv2
import os
path1 = 'Path to your training data'
path2 = 'Path to output grayscale map'
file_list = os.listdir(path1)#Traverse all the files in the folder into a list
for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):#Iterate through all files with the name'file_list' with the extension name'jpg'
        img = cv2.imread(path1+file)#Read the image just traversed and save it as a variable named'img'
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#Use the cvtColor('original image', convert from RBG and BGR color space to gray space)method of the cv2 library  to convert the original image named'img' into a grayscale image and save it as a variable named'gray'
        
        cv2.imwrite(path2+file,gray)#Use the imwrite ('stored target path', variable named'gray') method of the cv2 library to write to the target path
        print(file+'Conversion completed')
```

So that you can get the result you want

Comment: please describe your code, *write a program with the following content* is not really a solution

Comment: hi，@Abilogos
Thank you for your suggestion, because I just joined stackoverflow yesterday, so I am not familiar with the rules here. I will pay more attention when providing suggestions from others. Thank you again.